# link blade.php file to CSS laravel 5.x

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

i put my view.blade.php file in resources\views\admin\login\view.blade.php and using this code below to link it to css `<link href="{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet">`
my CSS file in folder public\css\style.css

I also add `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"` under required key in composer.json but it still not working.
another question: is it neccessary to run php artisan serve and run view.blade.php?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<link href="{!! HTML::style('public/css/style.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet">`.. Please Try it

Comment: it's not working? but i just open view.blade.php in chrome without run php artisan serve

Comment: Do you have put this code directly into your master layout blade or in view.blade.php. If you want to attach css file in your view.blade.php then write @stack('css') between <head></head> in your master layout file and write @push('css') <link href="{!! HTML::style('public/css/style.css') !!}" rel="stylesheet"> @endpush , then check

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to put *i*-tags around the *link*-tags but your link should be inside the *head*-tags. please verify this first.

your second question about artisan serve. yes you have to that. this will spin up the webserver and serve your php / html / css code to the browser. Laravel is a php framework so it needs some kind of web server to handle your php cod.

[Quote from laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/#server-requirements)

> If you have PHP installed locally and you would like to use PHP's
>   built-in development server to serve your application, you may use the
>   serve Artisan command. This command will start a development server at
>   http://localhost:8000

Comment: thanks for your notice.
after start artisan serve. how can i call link to my view.blade.php file?

Comment: did you made a route to it ? if you don't know what a route is, i do recommend a tutorial or something. watch this: [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch)

Comment: okay, i add this: Route::get('login', function() {
 return view('admin.login.view');
}); to route and then login "http://localhost:8000/login" but that page is blank. nothing to show and have no error